# While file doesn't contain string BASH

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am making a script for my school, and I was wondering how I could check a file, and if the string isn't in the file, do a code, but if it is, continue, like this:

```
while [ -z $(cat File.txt | grep "string" ) ] #Checking if file doesn't contain string
do
    echo "No matching string!, trying again" #If it doesn't, run this code
done
echo "String matched!" #If it does, run this code
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$ if grep "string" file;then echo "found";else echo "not found"
```

To do a loop :

```
$ while ! grep "no" file;do echo "not found";sleep 2;done
$ echo "found"
```

But be carefull not to enter an infinite loop. string or file must be changed otherwise the loop has no meaning.

Above if/while works based on the return status of the command and not on the result.
if grep finds string in file will return 0 = success = true
if grep does not find string will return 1 = not success = false

By using ! we revert the "false" to "true" to keep the loop running since while loops on something as soon as it is true.

A more conventional while loop would be similar to your code but without the useless use of cat and the extra pipe:

```
$ while [ -z $(grep "no" a.txt) ];do echo "not found";sleep 2;done
$ echo "found"
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but I would like it to keep printing "not found", until string is found.

Comment: @Python updated and explained. Is that what are you looking for...?

Comment: @George: Yes you gave a warning for an infinite loop, but your sample code is a bad example. Just add `sleep 1` to be safe.

Comment: Ideally, you want to use a tool provided by your operating system (e.g., `inotify` for Linux) to block your script until the file updates before running `grep` again, instead of polling the file for changes every X seconds.

Comment: @chepner Sounds a really good idea, but i really don't know what the OP wants to do with this code. I thought that this is just a kind of "demo code" for school demonstating while loops. If the purpose is polling a file until string to appear then this code is not efficient.

Answer (score 3):

A simple if statement to test if a 'string' is not in `file.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep -q string file.txt; then
    echo "string not found in file!"
else
    echo "string found in file!"
fi
```

The `-q` option (`--quiet`, `--silent`) ensures output is not written to standard output.

A simple while loop to test is a 'string' is not in `file.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! grep -q string file.txt; do
    echo "string not found in file!"
done
echo "string found in file!"
```

**Note:** be aware of the possibility that the while loop may cause a infinite loop!

Comment: Without the `-q` option for `grep` the string will be printed to standard output if found.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to just do the following:

```
[[ -z $(grep string file.file) ]] && echo "not found" || echo "found"
```

`&&` means AND - or execute the following command if the previous is **true**

`||` means OR - or execute if the previous is **false**

`[[ -z $(expansion) ]]` means return **true** if the expansion output is **null**

This line is much like a double negative, basically:
"return **true** if the string is **not found** in file.file; then echo **not found** if **true**, or **found** if **false**"

Example:

```
bashPrompt:$ [[ -z $(grep stackOverflow scsi_reservations.sh) ]] && echo "not found" || echo "found"
not found
bashPrompt:$ [[ -z $(grep reservations scsi_reservations.sh) ]] && echo "not found" || echo "found"
found
```